# Launching Blackberry application using Eclipse debugger resets device

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to debug a Blackberry application on device. I had some initial success, but lately the device reboots when the debugger tries to launch the application. The application gets installed, and I can run it from the device after the device reboots, but so far I'm unable to get it to run under the debugger.

Configuration

- Device: 9700 OS: v5.0.0.602
- Eclipse: Galileo (3.5.2) Blackberry Java
- Plug-in: 1.1.2.201004161203-16
- Blackberry SDK: 5.0.0.25

I've seen some references to this problem elsewhere, but no real solution. I've tried deleting the application from the device before launching the debugger, but I still get a reboot when the application installs. It appears that this problem may be related to the size of the application (it's getting big, and will get bigger). Small applications install and debug fine.

I'd be happy if I could install the application as one step and then attach the debugger as a second step, but this doesn't seem to be available from the Blackberry SDK. Only option I see is to install, launch, and debug.

Does anyone have a solution or work around to this problem? Thanks.

-rich

Comment: I had same problem with you. I have found a solution, [check this out](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Eclipse-pluging-1-1-quot-debug-as-Blackberry-device-quot/m-p/478185#M96.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found a solution to this problem. I had tried the suggestion of deleting the application from Options | Applications on the device. Turns out this did not completely remove the application. Some library modules remained behind. I was able to delete these from Desktop Manager. This is a somewhat cumbersome process, but it gets me unblocked for on device debugging.